# Why is it better to compile javascript to javascript?

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs, gulp

I am an experience software developer but new to web software engineering.

I just put myself behind a day in my internship exploring the Javascript Build Tool scene, and I see that there's about a thousand tools out there, like jasy, broccoli, brunch, etc.

But *WHY* compile javascript to javascript?  What is the purpose of it?

Thanx,
jb

Comment: Build tools do many things besides compile source code.

Answer (score 2):

**Grunt** is not really a compiling tool. Grunt is a tool with all sorts of addons used to minify html, to uglify scripts, to move items from your development folder to your dist-folder, run a local server (which is really handy with live-reload), watch changes to files,...

**Bower** is a building tool that helps organizing your front-end dependencies. You install the stuff through bower (with the node.js command-line) and save it in your application. That way you can easely manage your dependencies and the only thing you have to keep track of is (theoretically) your bower file. If you push it to Git someone else can easely install all the needed depdencies, based on your bower file.

All these tools are just for easiers project management, dependencies, and annoying tasks that otherwise take up a lot of your time.

edit: if you have specific questions regarding a specific tool, modify your question ;)

Comment: OK...so these build tools don't really do anything to the javascript. In C, a file could have an entire tree of include on include on include...so if you have javascript that has includes on includes, these tools help with that then...??

Comment: Yep, that's a bit of the idea. As mentioned Grunt has many plugins to handle all sorts of specific operations. for example Grunt-sass compiles your sass to javascript. Grunt is the framework for all these plugins to be used in. You make configurations for all these tasks in your gruntfile and then you can simply call them from the command line (or make a whole string of tasks and call this with one simple command). Alternative to Grunt is Gulp, that does the same. It's a bit faster but Grunt has more plugins overall.

Comment: OK, I get it...so I've been working with Dreamweaver for years, but I found an IDE for the Mac that is specifically designed to work with frameworks: CodeKit...thoughts about it anybody? long-time users?

Comment: I think this is a bit beyond the scope of your question. If you are going to go for front-end webdesign, you don't really need an IDE, you can do with a good text-editor like Sublimetext and node.js on the command-line. There are tons of resources out there, I don't have any experience with CodeKit itself. If you feel like your original answer was answered by my answer, you can always mark it as useful ;)